# Install SSL certificate from SIM card

Tags: certificates, mobile, android, ios, simcard

Are mobile network providers able to store their own SSL certificate on SIM cards, and auto-import this certificate into trust store on mobile phones (Android/iOS)?

I know that SIM cards can store some data and execute some code. So does some API (maybe private API) for SIM cards on mobile OS exist, that can be used to install certificate?

Comment: What makes you think they are?

Comment: @krazor nothing special, just theoretical question

Comment: I would reword your question towards a more specific scenario, for example something along the lines of "How can I read the contents of a SIM card" might yield better answers. As it stands right now you are asking if a provider 'is able to store a file in a SIM card' and if phones automatically read and act based on this file

Comment: So...they can store arbitrary extra data on SIM card, but they can't manipulate with it without external interference. That is, SIM card cannot ask the device to do something, because it outside of standard SIM communication protocol.

Comment: What APIs exist for phones (or carriers) would not appear to be a security question, although you have a security implication. It's more of a phone OS function question or a phone hardware programming question.

Comment: @schroeder, I disagree. Existance of this API is a security question, because if every mobile provider can install certificate into trust store, they can modify SSL traffic then.

Comment: There is no current API to do this, however a SIM is like any other smartcard (often a Javacard) and can have multiple "applications" on it - the device selects which one to use with the SELECT command. So the mobile side would keep using the SIM application while the OS could be extended to expose the SIM card reader to userspace and apps can then try and use other SIM apps like the PKI app (for certificates).

Comment: @g4s8 I get that, but you just outlined my point - the *implication* can touch on security, but the question is about the existence of a function. The security question would be "what is the impact of such a function" once we know the function exists ...